# Microsoft Lync OU Groups

Tags: lync, usergroups, ou

I can access the users in the domain by typing the contact name in the search box.

Is there a way in the Lync account to organize the users in the same domain into groups as Organizational Units?

Example:

```
Sales Department:
-User 1
-User 2
-User 3
HR Department:
-User 1
-User 2
Finance Department:
-User 1
-User 2
-User 3
-User 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Lync Client, then no (and you are asking in the wrong place).
If you are talking about the Lync Client SDK, it's a no but you can workaround it.

What I have done before is to do a LDAP query using [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate a list of email address, then using [GetContactByUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj274481.aspx) to generate a list of Lync Contacts to display in our own GUI.  This does assume email address matches the Lync sip address, which it may not.